# First pixel of the image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, pixel, scanning

I just scanned a sample image and I'm trying to detect the first pixel which has a value of "0" in the binary-image.
I used paint to write a text and when i used the following prog, it always catches the bottom most pixel.

```
    clear all;
    x=imread('textjay.png');
    y=im2bw(x);

    height=size(y,1); % row
    width=size(y,2);  % col

    valueoftheindex=0;

    pixel_value=0;

    for i=1:width
     for j=1:height
      pixel_value=y(j,i);
      if (pixel_value==0)
       valueofthewidth=i;
       valueofthehieght=j;
       break
      end
      end
     end

    valueofthewidth
    valueofthehieght

    imtool(y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends a lot on what you consider to be "the first pixel".
Assuming that you can live with the pixel order that MATLAB assigns you could use

```
idx = find(y == 0, 1, 'first')
[row_idx, col_idx] = ind2sub(size(y), idx)
```

For other measures of "firstness" you would have to either transpose the input matrix (the image), or resort to some more refined way of calculation.

And yes, the `break` will only break the inner loop, as dawe already pointed out.

Comment: +1 because you're solution works :).  Using the linear index is the way to go.  I was confused by the `[row, col] = find(X,...)` behaviour. I just simply removed my wrong answer.